# python encoding for turkish characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypdf

I have to read pdf books that are turkish stories. I found a library which is called pyPdf. My test function whichis the below doesn't encode correctly. I think, I need to have turkish codec packet. Am i wrong ? if i am wrong how can I solve this problem orelse how can I find this turkish codec packet?

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pyPdf,os

def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    num_pages = 10
    p = file(path, "rb")
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(p)
    for i in range(0, num_pages):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())   
    return content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdfContent = StringIO(getPDFContent(os.path.abspath("adiaylin-aysekulin.pdf")).encode("utf-8", "ignore"))
    for line in pdfContent:
        print line.strip()
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: What did you want to say ? Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error / unexpected output are you getting specifically?

According to the [pyPdf homepage](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/), pyPdf is no longer maintained. But there is a fork called [PyPDF2](http://knowah.github.io/PyPDF2/) ([GitHub](http://knowah.github.io/PyPDF2/)) that promises to "handle a wider range of input PDF instances".

Maybe upgrading to PyPDF2 solves your problem, I suggest you try that first.

Comment: I solved the problem in a different way. Before I have converted pdf to text and then i read the the text file.